# Can't SET/GET with NodeJS and Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, key-value, etherpad

I want to write a ueberDB Redis-Handler for my Etherpad.

I absolutely do not understand my problem because with PHP I can set and get key/values without any problems. It only does not work with NodeJS.

Here is a example code:

```
var redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();
client.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("test", "string val", redis.print);
console.log(client.get("test"));
```

What do I wrong? Maybe somebody has a tip for me.

Comment: Is have you set the host and port options correctly? `redis.createClient(port, host, options)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to know if your redis client is connected. You can check with console.log(client) and you will see a varaible called "connected". You should see "true"

If you want to use redis in node you should use something like this

```
    client.set("test","val", function(err) {
        if (err) {
           // Something went wrong
           console.error("error");
        } else {
            client.get("test", function(err, value) {
                 if (err) {
                     console.error("error");
                 } else {
                     console.log("Worked: " + value);
                 }
            });
        }
    });
```

Keep in mind that all redis function are asynchronous.

Comment: Well, be sure you're connected to redis and you can check the content of redis with the command "redis-cli" from CLI

Comment: redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set test test
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get test
"test"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> exit
[root@123 tmp]# node 1.js 
[root@123 tmp]#

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer. Since you're new: read the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

If it's not obvious from the accepted answer, the reason the posted code is failing is due to the asynchronicity.

You're calling get() before set() has completed.

Comment: hi Sir, what are the js or nodejs way of working around this asynchronicity that you mentioned. Seems, like the JS's event-driven way of doing things is getting in the way here...